# Mongoid and has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongodb, mongoid

I am using a HABTM association with Mongoid and I have the following scheme: 
    1) User has_and_belongs_to_many: specializations 
    2) Specialization has_and_belongs_to_many :users

it all works and I am happy, but I've noticed that user ids in any specialization instance are saved as an array, like so:

```
<Specialization _id: 52db847e6d69631dee000000, user_ids:      [BSON::ObjectId('52db84b66d69631dff000000'), BSON::ObjectId('52db88906d69631f17000000')]
```

And that's if I have just 2 users with this specialization, and when I imagine how huge it'll be when there are like 10,000 users, I am scared that I am gonna have quering and searching problems, even if I add an index on this field, and the size of the document will be big too I guess, could anybody tell me whether I should worry about perfomance problems and where I am wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concern is valid. I tried to use HABTM but it scaled very poorly. Embedding provided me with much faster speeds but I needed independently existing documents for the embedded model (and embedding means you cannot do that). Ultimately I just created a manual relation by having an array field to store the foreign IDs. Its quick and dirty but it solved my problem with scalability.

Comment: I think I'll leave the way it is but optimize queries with ".without" method, that'll probably mostly resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to reconsider if you want to use a HABTM relation or you can do it without mongoid's helpers.

You could consider embedding specialiazations to users, (but it depends on the volume of your data).

Now if the id style is inconvenient you could override it
eg. for Specialiazation

```
field :_id, as: :spec_id, type: String
before_save :set_id

...

private

def set_id
  #creates a simpler id
  #self.spec_id = ...
end
```

Provide some more info, concerning your models (records count, possible growth, what will you query, etc)